# What are the possible values for status of AWS API DBCluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

When querying the AWS API for [DescribeDBClusters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBClusters.html) the response is an array of [DBCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DBCluster.html). A `DBCluster` object contains a field `status` of type `String` with documentation

> The current state of this DB cluster.

Is there any guarantee or documentation about the possible values this field can take? So far I came across `available` and `failing-over`. It would be great if you could rely on a predictable result especially for `failing-over`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would guess it's these ones from the docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/accessing-monitoring.html#Aurora.Status